# Why does the callback on addEvenetListener print out old state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this callback function in which I set some state. The state seems to mutate just fine. However, I cannot refer to the updated state inside the callback function - it always prints out the initial state.

So my question is why this happens and how should I proceed if i want to check on the updated state inside the callback?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Context from "./ctx";

export default props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); <<---logs the initial state.
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize");
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); <<---logs updated versions of the state.

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        ...state
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: useState is async function. It couldn't be up to date when you try to reach it after it was updated. You can add a new useEffect callback with your state as array param: `useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]))`

Comment: @demkovych is correct, since state updaters are asynchronous, you can't assume the state has been updated until the next render

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing is related to two things:

1. How React works
2. Closures (function + environment in which it was created).

**1. How React works**
You've created and exported functional React component, which accepts some props, uses hooks for state management, and renders some content.
Whenever some props or state change in your component (or in it's parent component) react will re-render your component, meaning: it will literally call your function, like `yourComponent(props)`.
The point is: the body of your function will be executed every time re-render happens, alongside with calls to `useState` and `useEffect`.

**2. Closures (function + environment in which it was created)**

Whenever we create/define some function in JavaScript it is stored in the runtime memory alongside with the environment in which it was created.
In your case, you're defining the function in question (and providing it as a callback to `useEffect` at the same time) here:

```js
() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); <<---logs the initial state.
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize");
    };
  }
```

and the **environment** in which it's created is the body of your functional component.
So, whenever React calls your component the new environment is created, and new callback function is defined. But, because you provided empty array as second argument (which represents **dependencies array** [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)) here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`);
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize");
    };
  }, []); // <-- HERE
```

provided function will be executed only once - on component mount/first render, because you said it doesn't depend on any other value, so there's no need to fire that effect again.
Bottom line: You're defining new callback function on every render, but only first one was actually called. When it was defined, value of state was `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`. That's why you're always getting that value.

**Solution**
Depending on your needs, you can set dependencies in the second argument, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); 
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize");
    };
  }, [state]); // <-- NOW THE CALLBACK WILL BE EXECUTED EVERY TIME STATE CHANGES
```

or, you can omit second argument altogether, that way it will be fired on every render:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`);
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize");
    };
  }); // <-- WITHOUT SECOND ARGUMENT
```

It may seem expensive, but the official React documentation says it shouldn't have any performance hits with event listeners usage, because addEventListener DOM api is very efficient. But if you notice some performance issues, you can always use the first solution :).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason in javascript closures. `useEffect` callback has an old version of data because of empty deps array, outside data don't update. So your old version of `state` object is used. That is why you get the same values

Answer (score 0):

SetState is asynchronous, right after you execute that line of code you will get old values, one thing that you can do is listen for the *state* to be updated then output the console.log inside that effect, something like:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); //<<---Now it logs the actual state
  }, [state.x, state.y]);
```

Full Example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const App = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); //<<--- Now it logs the actual state
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
      setState({
        x: e.target.window.visualViewport.width,
        y: e.target.window.visualViewport.height
      });
      console.log("updated");
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handler);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(state)}`); //<<---logs updated versions of the state.

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      test
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-kowalevski-n87km